# JavaScript heap out of memory on npm run build - React

Tags: reactjs, build

After installing this library (**@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons**)  on a React project I'm getting this error when I run **npm run build**

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of 

memory
 1: 00007FF64BC481BA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF64BC22C56 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF64BC235D0 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF64BF3BA9E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF64BF3B9CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF64C1221C4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF64C1191A6 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF64C1177FC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF64C120547 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF64C1205C6 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF64C24A867 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF64C2C7A56 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
13: 000003FB8D75C5C1
```

I've tried things like increasing memory on the terminal: **set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"** , changing my nodejs version didn't work either.

This is my react version `"react": "^16.13.1",`, and I'm facing this error on windows 10.

Hope anyone has been able to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same here. Same version, after update.

Comment: downgraded to 16.13.0 and it went away